# Select average value X of SQL table column while not grouping by X

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

For the purposes of my question, I have a database in a MySQL server with info on many taxi rides (it is comprised of two tables, `history_trips` and `trip_info`).

In history_trips, each row's useful data is comprised of a unique alphanumeric ID, `ride_id`, the name of the rider, `rider`, and the time the ride ended, `finishTime` as a Y-m-d string.

In trip_info, each row's useful data similarly contains `ride_id` and `rider`, but also contains an integer, `value` (calculated in the back end from other data).

What I need to do is create a query that can find the average of all the maximum 'values' from all riders in a given time period. The riders included in this average are only considered if they completed less than X (let's say 3) rides within the aforementioned time period.

So far, I have a query that creates a grouped table containing the name of the `rider`, the `finishTime` of their highest 'value' ride, the `value` of said ride, and the number of rides, `num_rides`, they have taken in that time period. The `AVG(b.value)` column, however, gives me the same values as `b.value`, which is unexpected. I would like to find some way to return the average of the `b.value` column.

```
SELECT a.rider, a.finishTime, b.value, AVG(b.value), COUNT(a.rider) as num_rides
FROM history_trips as a, trip_info as b 
WHERE a.finishTime > 'arbitrary_start_date_str' and a.ride_id = b.ride_id 
and b.value = (SELECT MAX(value) 
from trip_info where rider = b.rider and ride_id = b.ride_id) 
GROUP BY a.rider
HAVING COUNT(a.rider) < 3
```

I am a novice in SQL but have read on some other forums that when using the `AVG` function on a value you must also `GROUP BY` that value. I was wondering if there is a way around that or if I am thinking of this problem incorrectly. Thanks in advance for any advice / solutions you might have!

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved. (And one of those two has a bit odd group by behavior.)

Comment: You need to join history_trips and trip_info.  Right now they are cross joined which will make everything the same value.  I haven't looked to in detail but you want and INNER JOIN on relationship which I think is history_trips.rideid = trip_info.rideid....

Comment: @Matt Thanks, I'll look into INNER JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
SELECT AVG(ridergroups.maxvalues) avgmaxvalues FROM
(SELECT MAX(trip_info.value) maxvalues FROM trip_info
INNER JOIN history_trips
ON trip_info.rideid = history_trips.ride_id
WHERE history_trips.finishTime > '2010-06-20'
GROUP BY trip_info.rider
HAVING COUNT(trip_info.rider) < 3) ridergroups;
```

The subquery groups the maximum values by rider after filtering by date and rider count. The containing query calculates the average of the maximum values.